# CDOSYS error using HTMLBody (all right with TextBody) in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message

I have a problem with CDOSYS with HTMLBody on IIS 7.5
Simply, this doesn't work:

```
Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With Mail
    .Subject = "My mail test"
    .From = "me@localhost"
    .To = "myrealmail@mydomain.com"
    .HTMLBody = "My body message"
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
    .Configuration.Fields.Update
    .Send
End With
Set Mail = Nothing
```

And throws a misterious *"CDO.Message.1 error '80040605' Unknown Error"* at line

```
.HTMLBody = "My body message"
```

No problem if I change it with

```
.TextBody = "My body message"
```

Please, have you got a solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look that, may be helps : http://forums.asp.net/post/1348573.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried to unregister/re-register cdosys.dll as suggested in that post, but no luck. Anyway I just discovered that it's a my-pc related issue: the same code on another machine (IIS 7.5 too) works perfectly... Well, I try to live with this problem on my development pc...

Comment: i do not have iis7.5 to check this but please try once in this form .HTMLBody = "<html><body>My body message</body></html>"

Comment: I've just come across this exact same behaviour. If I find a solution I'll post it. Just letting you know you're not going crazy. :)

Answer (score 6):

Found some kind of solution, though it's not ideal. CDO is supposed to be able to automatically generate the text-only version of your HTMLBody, but perhaps a recent MS update has broken it.

It seems that, where previously I could omit the TextBody property, and just specify HTMLBody, now I have to do either of these two things:

a) Specify TextBody. TextBody = "" does not work, it has to be > ""

b) Specify AutoGenerateTextBody = False

Doing either of those things gets around the error, but results in either no text-only version, or having to make it oneself, which sucks. No idea when this problem began, but afaik one used to be able to specify HTMLBody alone, without a problem. Dang.